How to remove Text Bouding box Bottom white space in illustrator?
anyone can help to solve the space below the text inside text bounding box in Adobe Illustrator ? please check the image for clarity.
I tired by converting to Area type  and adjusting are type options! then area bounding box can be adjustable , and the space remains, we can see the space while selecting the spac.


The basic answer is: No, you have no option to change a size of the space around a text. It's an inner feature of a font per se. (I'm a bit surprised the space below on your screenshot is too big, though. Probably there are some additional problems.) But there can be some particular solutions for particular cases. So, what you're trying to do? To measure the text? To align the text vertically with another object?
